# Echidna(Fuzz) assertion test fail about sending ether

Tags: blockchain, solidity, audit, fuzzer

I am currently testing assertions using Echidna.

[test file]

```
contract ReceiveEther {

    constructor() payable {}

    function receiveEther() public payable {
        uint256 amount = msg.value;
        assert(address(this).balance == amount);
    }
}
```

[yaml]

```
maxValue: 100000000000000000000 #100 eth
balanceContract: 0
```

[test command]

echidna-test --config ./echidna.yaml ./ReceiveEther.sol --contract ReceiveEther --test-mode assertion

[Result]

```
receiveEther(): failed!  
  Call sequence:
    receiveEther() Value: 0x1
    receiveEther()

Event sequence: Panic(1)
```

The test result was expected to be passed. But for some reason
the fuzz test does not pass like above log.

I don't know why the following line doesn't pass in Echidna:

assert(address(this).balance == amount);

If anyone knows the reason, please tell me.